# Salesforce Embedded Login - having issues rendering the login component due to CSP ancestors-frame

Tags: connected-apps, authentication, experience-cloud, embedded

I am trying to implement the Embedded login functionality to allow community users to authenticate through the embedded login form on an external site. I have the domain allowed through CORS settings and have created the connected app as per the documentation here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_login_all_steps.htm

I am using an example repo to deploy to Heroku to try and test the embedded login. Here is the repo: https://github.com/salesforceidentity/embedded-login-example

When I try to load the page, I get an error when loading the embedded login component

Refused to frame 'https://rwdev10-salesportal.cs64.force.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".

I tried adding
 to the page to allow the heroku page hosting the embedded login form to be accessible. However this does not work.

Has anyone had issues with frame-ancestors and embedded login? Salesforce documentation only says I need to open the domain in CORS, which I have done.

Thanks